# view.layer drawInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() not drawing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cgimage, cgimageref, uigraphicscontext

I am trying to draw a `UIView` into a `UIImage`. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.bounds.size, YES, 0.f);
[myView.layer drawInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I've verified `myView.bounds.size` to be valid. `myView` displays correctly on screen. However, `img` is completely black (I've tried displaying on both in an `UIImageView` and tried writing the JPEG representation to file.) The image dimensions are correct, the color space (in JPEG file output) is RGB, color profile is sRGB etc. which means that we're not dealing with a corrupted image (in the sense that image/bitmap data itself is valid). I've tested the case on both 6.0 simulator, 7.0 simulator, and 7.0.6 device, all the same. The layer doesn't have any sublayers, and I've tried setting `masksToBounds` to `NO` which didn't change anything.

What could be causing the view's layer not to draw?

Comment: what kind of content/layers are in your view? does it have children?

Comment: it's a regular `CALayer` of a `UIView`. no, it doesn't have any sublayers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change:

`[myView.layer drawInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`

to:

`[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`

Note that `drawInContext:` does not actually do anything by default:

> The default implementation of this method does not doing any drawing
>   itself. If the layer’s delegate implements the drawLayer:inContext:
>   method, that method is called to do the actual drawing.
>
> Subclasses can override this method and use it to draw the layer’s
>   content. When drawing, all coordinates should be specified in points
>   in the logical coordinate space.

A UIView's layer delegate is set to the UIView, but it does not look like the UIView necessarily draws to the provided context.  More investigation is necessary on this point.

Comment: I've changed it to `renderInContext:` but it still renders black.

Comment: That makes me thing you have an alpha channel that's not being honored.  Try setting the opaque parameter to NO.  I was able to write out a PNG file using your code with the change I suggested.

Comment: When I set `opaque` to `NO` I'm getting a fully transparent image, and when I put that into `UIImageView`, it's not visible at all.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling this on a UIView with content?  Try rendering `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] layer]`.

Comment: `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] layer]` renders correctly.

Comment: Yeah, so it sounds like something strange is going on with UIScrollView, although I have no idea what.  I'd have to contrive a project to figure it out.  You can also try snapshotting your UIScrollView's parent.  I would expect that to capture the image even if UIScrollView is doing some magical rendering.

Answer (score 1):

**update**: per Rob Jones' comment, not these APIs return UIViews, not images.

There is a new API in iOS 7 that looks promising:

```
- (UIView *)snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
- (UIView *)resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:(CGRect)rect afterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates withCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);  // Resizable snapshots will default to stretching the center
- (BOOL)drawViewHierarchyInRect:(CGRect)rect afterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Check the `UIView (UISnapshotting)` category in `UIView.h`

Comment: they look nice, but I also want to support iOS 6, so even if I conditionally use this API on iOS 7, I still need a fallback scenario on iOS 6.

Comment: How is this promising?  This API just returns another UIView which doesn't really advance the goal of storing the contents of the current view to a UIImage.  I'm serious.  If this makes it easier, I'd really like to know how.

Comment: Actually it solves my problem as I need another view to display (which I am trying with UIImageView to display the image), but if I actually needed an image, yeah, this API wouldn't work.

Comment: @RobJones you're right--if OP wants an image, this won't help. I didn't read carefully enough.